# Magnific Popup Not working properly when i try to call it on page load time or via onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am using Magnific Popup.

i am calling "call_popup" page on button onClick  (  )

```
function call(){
    $.magnificPopup.open({
              items: {
                src: '<?php echo SITEURL;?>flows/call_popup',
                type: 'ajax',closeOnContentClick : false, closeOnBgClick :true, showCloseBtn : false, enableEscapeKey : false,
                closeMarkup: '<button class="mfp-close mfp-new-close" type="button" title="Close (Esc)"> { costume button with close icon image } </button>'
              }
            });
}
```

popup is working fine , but closeOnContentClick,showCloseBtn,enableEscapeKey and closeMarkup 
not working. its behave like default popup. i dont what to close pop-up when user click on bg click.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function call(){
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            src: '<?php echo SITEURL;?>flows/call_popup',
            type: 'ajax',
        },
        closeOnContentClick : false, 
        closeOnBgClick :true, 
        showCloseBtn : false, 
        enableEscapeKey : false,
        closeMarkup: '<button class="mfp-close mfp-new-close" type="button" title="Close (Esc)"> { costume button with close icon image } </button>'

    });
}
```

Comment: One more plz 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908580/how-to-open-popup-within-popup-in-magnific-popup-plugin